# How to set ios theme in framework7

Tags: css, html, html-framework-7

I have used [android framework7 theme](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/3.3.2/css/framework7.min.css) it worked good but [ios framework7 theme](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/3.3.2/css/framework7.ios.min.css) is not working...
What should i do...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the theme param when you are creating the application.

```
var app = new Framework7({
  root: '#app',
  theme: 'ios' // can be 'auto' and 'md' also
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why the question got voted down as the Framework 7 documentation doesn't mention this in the examples page.. and it looks like some of the styles that were applied to everything in v1 are only applied to iOS in v2.